# Rails 7 - ActiveRecord::Associations::Preloader.new.preload

Tags: ruby-on-rails-6, ruby-on-rails-7

consider this code:

```
# in Rails 6.1
def preload(resource, relations)
  ActiveRecord::Associations::Preloader.new.preload(resource, relations)
end
```

So:
I want to change that for compatibility with Rails 7 so I wrote this:

```
def preload(resource, relations)
  ActiveRecord::Associations::Preloader.new(records: resource, associations: relations)
end
```

Did I do a right thing? because .preload(resource, relations) is not exit in Rails 7 anymore.
if you have any other suggestion I'm so looking forward for it

Answer (score 13):

You're almost there. It looks like this works:

```
    ActiveRecord::Associations::Preloader.new(
      records: [resource].flatten, # in case if resource is a single ApplicationRecord object
      associations: relations
    ).call
```